# Example of entire function which can take every value except .....

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions, entire-functions

> Example of entire function which can take every value except 1) Finite Number of Points 2) Countable Number Of points

I know about example of function which does not take only single value and entire function 
I could not able to find example of entire which is not take only finite number point in C and entire function which does not take countable number of values
Does such function exist?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The [Little Picard Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_theorem) settles this point.  If your entire function is not a constant, then it can miss at most one point.

Comment: Thanks a lot .I had been not know that theorem before

Comment: Another important, related theorem is known as the Bigger Picard Theorem.